# Writing gstreamer plugins in windows

Tags: gstreamer

I am required to write a plugin for gstreamer. The code which will be integrated in the plugin  is actually available as VS 2005 project. That's why I intend to develop the plug as well in visual studio. I couldn't find any resources which talks about setting up gstreamer plugin dev environment in windows as Visual Studio Project.

The gstreamer windows SDK doesn't contain the required files for plugin development as mentioned in http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/pwg/html/chapter-building-boiler.html.

Note:
The following question though similar is not what I am looking for : 
[Needed environment for building gstreamer plugins in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2996565/needed-environment-for-building-gstreamer-plugins-in-windows)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To develop GStreamer plugins on Windows you can use the GStreamer SDK.

The chapter **Constructing the Boilerplate** is focused on Linux development and it references to the git repository *gst-template*, which contains templates for building plugins and apps using the Autotools build system. Since you will use VS, you will only the source code templates, that you can directly download [here](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-template/tree/gst-plugin/src).

Building a plugin is similar to building a GStreamer application in terms of dependencies and in the [SDK documentation](http://docs.gstreamer.com/display/GstSDK/Installing+on+Windows) you will find detailed explanations on how to create new VS projects (in the section **Creating new projects using the wizard**).

To build your plugin you will need:

1. Create a new GStreamer project in VS as explained in the docs
2. Add the template sources of gst-template

Comment: http://docs.gstreamer.com/display/GstSDK/Installing+on+Windows Link is no longer valid.